# Disable component reusing on route params change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I upgraded angular2 application to stable release (from rc1), and noticed that `ngOnDestroy` is not triggered when route params are changed.

With previous version, when changing url from `match/123` to `match/124`, onDestroy was called and I was able to do some cleaning (e.g. unsubscribing from websocket for that particular match).

With this new behaviour, I'm not sure what is the best way to do the same? Can I force component to be re-initialized again?

this is parent structure, and mentioned component is rendered withing router-outled

```
    <div id="content">
      <live-sidebar-component></live-sidebar-component>

      <div id="page-wrapper">

        <live-breadcrumbs></live-breadcrumbs>

        <div id="page">
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="promobar">
        <ticket-component></ticket-component>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plans to bring support for `canReuse`.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846 for more details.

As a workaround you can subscribe to params changes and do the cleanup there instead:

```
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.params = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        // do cleanup
        console.log(params['someParam']);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I thought about that. But once I move to another match, I want to unsubscribe from previous, but I don't have information about previous route params. Is that possible or I need to keep it in class property?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to store it. But in this case `ngOnDestroy()` should be called.

Comment: ok, then I'll store it. Can you please be more clear regarding `in this case ngOnDestroy should be called`? In which case (in case where I store route in property)? Why it is important to call ngOnDestroy?

Comment: I mean't when you navigate away entirely from this route (not only changing route params). Maybe I misunderstood your first comment.

Comment: yes, in case I move completely to new route, I will handle socket unsubscribing with onDestroy. And if only params are changed, then I will solve it as you suggested (keep previous params in property, and on params change, I will do unsubscribing). Does it sound like a good approach?

Comment: I have the same problem and need the router to reattach a new view when navigating to a different param. Can you explain what you specifically mean with "do clean up"?

Comment: The "cleaning" (`ngOnDestroy`) mentioned in the question.